# Scraping more that the first page of YouTube video with inputted keywords

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, youtube, screen-scraping, pytube

I am trying to scrape YouTube videos based on a certain (or set of ) keywords. So far I can download only the first page of YouTube videos - roughly 20-30 videos. So far, I have used BeautifulSoup, urllib.request and pytube to do the needful. I am attaching some code here : how would I go about downloading more/all of the videos related to a specific keyword?

```
 # Search through divs 
    for i in divs:
        href= i.find('a', href=True)
        urls.append([href.text,"https://www.youtube.com"+href['href']])
        video_details = {}
        hashtags = []
        for link in divs:
            for span in link.findAll('span', attrs = {'class':'standalone-collection-badge-renderer-text'}):
                for a in link.findAll('a',attrs={'class': 'yt-uix-sessionlink'}):
                    hashtags.append(a.text.strip())
                    video_details['HASH_TAGS'] = hashtags
        #print(hashtags)

def Downloader(url):
    yt = pytube.YouTube(url)
    video = yt.streams.first()
    video.download('x')
```

Comment: Are you trying to scrape only the hashtags of the YouTube videos?

Comment: @abdullahalali i am trying to download the actual video itself along with titles, urls and the hashtags